# After update, background turned black, the dock is missing

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode

As you can see it, after updating the commandline tools for xcode, the background turned black and the dock is missing

[image]

the OS is macOS Sierra 10.12.4(16E195)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just checking, have you restarted your Mac? If not, what have you tried (if anything)?

Comment: @Monomeeth, I have restarted my mac for many times, still doesn't work.

Comment: @GoingMyWay, did this get fixed? How?

Answer (score 3):

This is now a famous glitch in the MacOS (i.e., OS level) and no one knows the solution except Apple Genius folks as they have been getting more and more of this issue recebtly. Contrary to popular attempts, this problem is **NOT SOLVED** by:

- Updating DisplayDriver
- Resetting **NVRAM** or **PRAM**
- Trying uselessly to `killall Dock` (in fact, that will tell you that no matching process found in your name)
- Booting in **Safe mode**
- And there’s no problem in your monitor!

### Here's the solution (latest, 2020):

In System Preferences → Displays → Arrangement tab, you have to drag and drop the exact white bar which represents the dock (not the blue screen) anywhere on the monitor and leave. Problem solved. Then optionally drag it back to wherever you want. This also works for a multi-monitor setup, as is my case below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On rare occasions, I have had to go nuclear and clean out specific preference files:

`rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

One might argue that you should back it up first. In that light, I suggest simply moving it out of the way and force-quitting Finder.

`cd ~/Library/Preferences
mv com.apple.finder.plist com.apple.finder.plist-orig`

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: Does Command-Option-D bring the Dock back?  Can you change the Dock and Desktop/Screensaver settings in System Preferences?

Comment: command-option-d can't bring the dock back, and I can't even change the background picture. And there is a ReportCrash process running on the os.

Comment: Can you log in as a different user?  If one doesn't exist, create a new one and log in on that account.  If it comes up happy, then there's something else wrong with your user account and you may need to delete it and recreate it.

Comment: It is the same case in the guest user account.

Comment: Try reinstalling Xcode.  If that doesn't work, try reinstalling Sierra from Recovery mode to help clean things up.  It shouldn't overwrite user files, just system files (that at this point appear to be corrupt).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else gets this, I had the same problem since updating to Big Sur, even reinstalling macOS via recovery didn't work.

However, after digging through running/uninstalling all my Applications, I had 'MacForge' installed, for some reason opening it immediately fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Answering for Ventura 13.3 on my 15" 2016 MacBook Pro.

I got the glitch after messing around and trying to change my desktop wallpaper from the command line. I reinstalled the entire operating system, and the issue persisted.

It seems like there are a variety of ways for this problem to occur, but for me, I had to delete the desktoppicture.db file, which for me was the only file located in: 
 ~/Users/YourUsername/Library/Application Support/Dock

I deleted that, then after a reboot the wallpaper was back to a default one. Hope this helps, especially since the accepted answer references settings that I do not believe exist anymore on Ventura (not that it was a bad answer, just potentially dated).

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments to the accepted answer had the solution in my case. Just run the following keyboard command a couple of times to hide/unhide your dock and it will probably flush out the problem:

```
Command-Option-D
```